# Server requires PHP strict comparison but not on localhost

Tags: php, comparison-operators

I've run across a weird issue with comparison operators.

On my localhost this code runs fine:

```
$variable = 2;
if($variable == 2){
  echo 'hi';
}
if($variable == '2b'){
  echo 'bye';
}
//returns 'hi'
```

But on my server, it returns 'bye', unless I use the strict (===) operator.

Is there any way to change this so my server also returns 'hi'?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use strict comparison operators?

Comment: I can, but I'd really like to know WHY it isn't working.

Comment: @Robbie try to var_dump the `$variable` to see what it is

Comment: @Robbie logically the value of `$variable` is not the same locally and on the server. The behavior of `==` does not change with php version/environment/OS etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is because php try to cast `(int)` to your string because you compare an `int` with a `string` so your if block would be

```
if($variable == (int) '2b'){
```

So when casting to it, so `(int) '2b'` would be only `2`.
If you use `===` it works cause of, that is also check if it is the same type.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar situation in the past. It's silly, but make sure you are running the same PHP version in both servers.

Either way, your production server works as it should, but your local server doesn't. Test:

```
echo 2 == '2b' ? 'true' : 'false'; // true
echo 2 == 'b2' ? 'true' : 'false'; // false
```

A string will be 'casted' into a number if it starts with a number.